# One off configuration for a @SpringBootTest

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing

How can I bootstrap my Spring Boot 2 integration tests so that across all of them I can have one set of configurations which pre-seeds the test database with some test data that can be used across all integration tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing you are using h2 test database.

My **src/test/resources/application.properties** file has:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

You'll need a configuration file with the following structure. (This is a configuration example located inside the folder **src/test/java**):

```
@Profile("test")
@Configuration
public class H2Config {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource datasource;

    @PostConstruct
    public void loadSQL() throws Exception {
        ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(datasource.getConnection(), new ClassPathResource("/sql/load_database.sql"));
    }
}
```

The file 'load_database.sql': (the full path is **/src/test/resources/sql/load_database.sql**)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE OPER_DISPN(
    ID          NUMBER NOT NULL,
    DT_VCTO_OPER  DATE         NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO OPER_DISPN(ID,DT_VCTO_OPER) VALUES (1,TO_DATE('2018/09/21', 'yyyy/mm/dd'));
```

If you are using mapped entities(with @Entity) ( with create-drop) you won't need the 'CREATE TABLE' part for that.

And now, all your integration tests have the script data inserted

**Edit: ( My test structure)** I've created at github my example application. Please see the test structure and run the tests:

```
TNotMappedRepository.testLoadDataFind()
PersonRepository.testLoadDataFind()
```

Github: https://github.com/thiagochagas/insert-data-tests

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @ThiagoChagas. Is this leveraging Spring's DI framework? I gave it a go but I'm seeing that the Configuration class and the `@PostConstruct` method is being invoked twice. Is this expected?

Comment: No, this isn't the expected. I tested with my application however it passes only one time. I will add more information about my test structure.

Comment: @n00b I have seen that if your script has errors It will run twice (the Configuration part). Is there any error log?

Comment: Thanks for the repo link. I was missing the `@ActiveProfile` and `@Profile` annotations